# Regular expression back reference inside the group it references

Tags: regex, backreference

Just encountered a regex which I have never seen before because I'd have never thought to try it:

```
((hello)\2)
```

I would have assumed this is an error. The back reference is referencing the group that it's actually in. This seems valid though and will match:

```
hellohello
```

Can someone explain the logic please? I presume this falls under the category of a nested back reference (or maybe even a forward reference) but the logic employed is unclear to me.

This case seems similar to "Nested References" here http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html but it's not the same as far as I can see.

FYI I'm already 99.9% sure I'd never use this in a production environment. I don't think I'd wish that upon any colleague!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((hello)\2)

^====1st group
 ^===2nd group
```

`2nd` group contains `hello` and `\2` matches it. So you get `True` for `hellohello`.

Comment: Ah, strange, that feels kind of obvious now. It's just a forward reference. I kept reading the groups the other way around. I think my brain was considering the inner group to be group 1 as it'll be the first to be matched not the first to be encountered. Thanks.